# How can i use an Excel File in a Static Resource and Access its Fields in Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to get values in my code from a static resource file.
I am using an excel file in a static resource, I want to know how I can map fields in an excel file to salesforce fields in my code. for example Account.Name etc

Lead l = new Lead();
l.Company = $Resource.EMailServicesLead.EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv;
\ Not Working
EMailServicesLead - Name of the static resource.
EmailServiceStaticResourceData - csv file with fields {FirstName, LastName, Email, Company, Status, LeadSource}

/**
 * @File Name          : myHandler.cls
 * @Description        : 
 * @Author             : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
 * @Group              : 
 * @Last Modified By   : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
 * @Last Modified On   : 7/10/2019, 3:54:01 PM
 * @Modification Log   : 
 * Ver       Date            Author                 Modification
 * 1.0    7/10/2019   ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc     Initial Version
**/
global with sharing virtual class myHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler
{
   global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) 
  { Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

```
  //Lead l= (Lead)ListofLeadsStaticRes[0];
  // List<SObject> ListofLeadsStaticRes = {!URLFOR($Resource.EMailServicesLead, 'EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv')};
  Integer j=0;
  String myPlainText= '';

   staticResource sr = new staticResource();
   List<sObject> ls = Test.loadData(Lead.sObjectType, 'myResource');
  // {!URLFOR($Resource.EMailServicesLead,EMailServicesLead/EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv)}

  Lead l = new Lead();
  l.FirstName=email.fromName.substring(0,email.fromName.indexOf(''));
  l.LastName=email.fromName.substring(email.fromName.indexOf(''));
  l.Email = envelope.fromAddress;
  myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;
  l.Company = $Resource.EMailServicesLead.EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv;
  l.Status = $Resource.EMailServicesLead.EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv;
  l.LeadSource = $Resource.EMailServicesLead.EmailServiceStaticResourceData.csv;
  l.Description = 'Mr.' + l.FirstName + l.LastName + ' enquired about the product Fin' + ' via' + ' Ëmail' + 'with body '+myPlainText;

  Task[] newTask = new Task[0];
  try { // Add a new Task to the Lead record we just found above.
       List<Lead> vLed = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress LIMIT 1];
       if(vLed.size()>0)
        { newTask.add(new Task(Description =  myPlainText,
                                  Priority = 'Normal',
                                  Status = 'Inbound Email',
                                  Subject = email.subject,
                                  IsReminderSet = true,
                                  ReminderDateTime = System.now()+1,
                                  WhoId =  vLed[0].Id));
          insert newTask;
          System.debug('New Task Object: ' + newTask ); 
        }
       else 
        {
          insert l;
          System.debug('Lead Created'+ l.Id);
        }
       }
    catch (QueryException e) {  System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e); }     
    return  result;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the CSV to extract the data from it. To make this easier you can use [this simple CSV parser class written by Nicolas Galler](https://gist.github.com/nicocrm/858086). Have a look through the code so you get how it works but all you will use is the constructor and the `readLine()` method that returns the list of values from each row of your CSV as Strings. You'll have to copy and paste the code from that link into an apex class named "SSSCsvReader" to be able to use it then in your code you will...

**1. get your static resource CSV as a String**

```
StaticResource sr = [SELECT ID, body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'EMailServicesLead' LIMIT 1];
String csvData = sr.body.toString();
```

**2. Create an instance of `SSSCsvReader`** by calling the constructor passing in the CSV string as the argument(and optionally, the second argument of a delimiter but the comma is the default)

`SSSCsvReader csvR = new SSSCsvReader(csvData);`

**3. Use the `readLine()` on your SSSCsvReader** object to get CSV field values in a String list. (if Your file has a header row on it don't forget to remove this first by calling `readLine()` once before getting your data list).

```
csvR.readLine() //Removing header (optional)
String[] line = csvR.readLine();
if(line == null){return null} //No line in the file or there was no header so return
```

**4. Assign each field** in the returned list from `readLine()` to the corresponding field in your salesforce object.

```
Lead l = new Lead();
l.firstName = line[0]; //If your file is laid out like you said FirstName will be index [0]
l.lastName = line[1]; //LastName will be index [1]
.... //And so on
....
....
```

And there you have it a Lead object with fields from your CSV static resource file. If you have more rows on you CSV and want to create many leads than just set up a while loop that gets each line from the CSV using `readLine()`, create a new lead from this line and add it to a list.